# Best way to uninstall/delete everything related to Emacs/Python/Django on OSX Lion

Tags: python, django, emacs, uninstallation

I am starting (and loving it) with python django or emacs on my OSX Lion. However I am pretty sure that I messed some stuff, and now I get some errors due to my ignorance when I was installing stuff or maybe because I did what I wasn't suppose to do in the Terminal.
Is there any way to clean all my emacs, python and django stuff from my system?
If so, how can I do it and whats the best way to make a solid install again, of the items mentioned?
Thank you all in advance for the help.
Merry Christmas to all.

Comment: If you describe the error you are getting, you'll get better responses.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to clean all my emacs, python and django stuff from my system?

Slow down.

Do NOT remove Python.  Mac OS X relies, absolutely on Python.  You can -- with some difficulty -- try to remove some versions, but it usually ends badly.  Mac OS X already included Python.  There probably was no reason to mess with it.

If you did, you'll need to provide details of what's in  /Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework/Versions

Emacs is hard to mess up.  I can't see why you'd bother trying to delete it.

Django, similarly, is hard to mis-install.  However, it's the easiest to remove because it's in your Python library site-packages

You'll have several site-packages, with paths like the following.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages

> whats the best way to make a solid install again, of the items mentioned?

You already have Python.  It's part of Mac OS X.  You can install others, but you have to pay attention and write down which versions you've installed.

If you install others, then you must use `python2.7` or `python2.6` to execute specific Python versions if you have multiple versions.

Emacs may have already been installed.

Django is most easily installed by using `pip` or `easy_install`.  Research those first.  Install them.  Then use them to install Django.